# Overcome list immutability?

Tags: ocaml, tic-tac-toe

```
let board =[0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0];;
```

I am trying to change the value of `board` using the returned vals of some of the functions that I wrote.
This is going to be my game loop:

```
let rec f gamestate = match gamestate with
9 -> ()
| _ ->
let _ = print_board board in
let _ = print_string "\n" in
let _ = print_string "row: " in
let row = read_int () in
let _ = print_string "col: " in
let col = read_int () in
board = (player_move board row col);
(*trying to change the value of board to (player_move board row col)*)

f (gamestate + 1);;
f 0;;
```

I have ensured that all the functions perform as intended. 
I was able to do so by:

```
let _ = print_board (player_move board row col) in
```

This gives me the output as I expect it to be but I have no way of "saving" the newly modified `board`

Do I have to use an `Object` instead?

Comment: A good (and common) reason to study OCaml is to learn to work with immutable values. You can solve this problem without using objects or other immutable values. And I'd suggest you try to do that. But it depends somewhat on why you're doing this coding in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essential trick is to make `board` a *parameter* of f. Then you can call `f` recursively with the new board.

Comment: Yep that worked. I don't understand how I didn't think of that!